# InDesign-like "Background Tasks" panel in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, save, file-size, plugin

Is there a plugin or something that supplies a InDesign-like "Background Tasks" panel to e.g. monitor the saving process of files? I'd like to be able to monitor this process when in fullscreen mode, this is helpful when saving large files as my Mac tends to slow down exponentially..

I'm using Photoshop CC 2015.

Comment: I think this question is more a tech support than design question. AFAIK you can just use your OS's system monitor to do this task.